# How to submit a form by id or class parameter with custom ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I don't want to write ajax call every time as my API URL, post method, and form id or class name will change according to page, so I am trying to create a custom function which will handle the API call with respect to the parameters passed.
and  the mandatory parameter are pass form id, post type, url ,data... etc

```
$("#contactForm").submit(function(e) {

        var url = "https://api.sample.com/V2.0/apinamewillchange"; // the script where you handle the form input.

        $.ajax({
             //crossDomain: true,
               type: "POST",
               url: url,
               data: $("#contactForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
               success: function(data)
               {
                   var loginresponse = data;

                   console.log(loginresponse); // show response from the php script.

               }
             });

        e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    });
```

and how I am looking to create is, not exactly but some thing what I tried

```
    function customRequest(postype,url,data,formid) {
           $(formid).submit(function(e) {
       var promise = $.ajax({
         type: t,
         data: d,
         url: u
       })


       return promise;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow this

this function call your custom ajax and pass your desired ajax attributes such as (url, method type, data, callback, etc)

```
function sendAJax1() {
    var type = "POST";
    var url = "https://api.sample.com/V2.0/ajax1.php";
    var data = $("#form1").serialize();
    var formid = "#form1";

    customRequest(type, url, data, formid, function(data) {
        // do something with your ajax callback
    } );
}

function sendAJax2() {
    var type = "POST";
    var url = "https://api.sample.com/V2.0/ajax2.php";
    var data = $("#form2").serialize();
    var formid = "#form2";

    customRequest(type, url, data, formid, function(data) {
        // do something with your ajax callback
    } );

    e.preventDefault(); // avoid 
}
```

this function read submit event of your specified form and send ajax request with it's specified (url, method type, data, callback, etc)

```
function customRequest(postype, url, data, formid, callback) {

    $(formid).on('submit', function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            //crossDomain: true,
            type: postype,
            url: url,
            data: data, // serializes the form's elements.
            success: function(data) {
                return callback(data);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault(); // avoid 
    })
}
```